# What cultures can be added to pasteurized milk to allow it to clabber like raw milk?

Tags: food-safety, milk, dairy, cultured-food

I have a dairy cow, and when I leave its raw milk on the counter for a couple of days, I end up with [clabber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clabber_(food)) (also called clabbered milk). However, I am not willing to take the risk of consuming non-pasteurized milk products during a global health pandemic. I want to try out some recipes that use uncooked clabber. And since there are cultures that can be added to pasteurized milk to make kefir, yogurt, and cheeses, I thought surely there must be some that can be added to make clabber! Alas, I have not been able to find any information on this.

**What specific bacterial, fungal, or yeast cultures can be added to pasteurized milk to create clabber?**

Comment: https://joepastry.com/2014/is-clabber-anything-like-yogurt-2/ suggests it's just a difference in cultures ... but I have no idea where you'd get that specific culture so that you could use pasteurized milk.  Do you have a source of clabber that you *know* is untainted, so you could just use it like active culture yogurt?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to guaranteed-safe clabber from which I could culture more.

Comment: What is the relationship between your home-clabbered milk and covid-19? ...and what do you do with the rest of your cow's milk?

Comment: @Kerrick the wiki article you linked says "A somewhat similar food can be made from **pasteurized milk by adding a couple of tablespoons of commercial buttermilk or sour milk** to a glass of milk.[1]"

Answer (score -1):

I have made something like a yoghurt using just kefir and pasteurized milk. One of the two bottles was in equilibrium. Sour and with bubbles. Not so lucky though with the other bottle as it was more like yeast in taste.